# Wix C# Custom Action Logging Not Working

Tags: wix

I am trying to log from my C# Custom Action using session.Log( "Hello World!" ); This does not show up in my log file when executing my msi as follows:

**msiexec /i myMsi.msi /lvx myLog.log**

My custom action works fine, my only problem is I do not get *my* logging info. The log shows my CA is getting called, just not the info from my session.Log() call.

I am using Wix 3.5, .Net 4, VS 2010, and 64-bit Windows 7. I am calling my action as follows.

```
<Control Id="TestConnection" Type="PushButton" X="21" Y="177" Width="100" Height="17" Text="Test Connection">
  <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="TestConnection">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Per the docs on [DoAction ControlEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368322(VS.85).aspx), MsiProcessMessage (the API behind session.Log) cannot be used from a ControlEvent. This prevents your message from showing up in the log. If you need to log some information from a ControlEvent (especially for debugging), your best bet is a hack like changing a property's value to contain your desired log information.

Comment: Also session.Message relies on the same MsiProcessMessage (and not Message as one would hope)

Comment: >  On systems prior to Windows Server 2003, custom actions launched by a DoAction ControlEvent cannot send messages with MsiProcessMessage or Message Method. For more information, see Sending Messages to Windows Installer Using MsiProcessMessage.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by using the unmanaged OutputDebugString:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern void OutputDebugString(string message);

public bool IsDebugLogging { get; set; }

public void Log(string message)
{
    // Uncomment if you have access to the Session object passed into your custom action.
    // Session.Log(message);
    if (IsDebugLogging)
    {
        OutputDebugString(message);
    }
}
```

In my custom action, I set IsDebugLogging = true to enable OutputDebugString logging. This output can be viewed using [Sysinternal's DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview).

Comment: Hi, when I do this I get the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `Session.Log(string)`". How can this be helped?

Comment: You can comment out the Session.Log line; that is the Session object that is passed into your custom action, in this case I am only using it to attempt to log to the Session as well as the debug window.