# wix - session.message is not showing at time of installation

Tags: installation, wix

Wix CustomAction [C#] `session.Message(Messagebox)` is not displayed during installation.

I have a Session.Message added in my custom action,

```
public static ActionResult DisplayConfirmationMessage(Session session) { 
    Record record = new Record(); 
    record.FormatString = pMessage; 
    Session.Message(InstallMessage.Error 
            | (InstallMessage)System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning 
            | (InstallMessage)System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, record); 
}
```

And in wxs file custom action

```
<CustomAction Id="RestartAction" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="DisplayMessage" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
```

and in install execute (only one custom action call):

```
<InstallExecute>
<Custom Action="RestartAction" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>     
</InstallExecute>
```

the message box is displayed only at time of uninstall. But during installation it is getting logged to session.Log.
I have checked with 'NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE' still same results.

I am blocked on this, please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depending on when you're scheduling your action, this may be addressed by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494101/wix-c-sharp-custom-action-logging-not-working/3503257

Comment: You should edit the question to show your custom action declarations and when it is called (if Michael's comment doesn't apply).

Comment: [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult DisplayConfirmationMessage(Session session)
 { Record record = new Record();
record.FormatString = pMessage;
Session.Message(InstallMessage.Error |
(InstallMessage)System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning |
(InstallMessage)System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, record);
}

this is my custom action method. 
<CustomAction Id="Action" BinaryKey="Test.CustomActions" DllEntry="DisplayConfirmationMessage" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncWait" />
this is my customaction call
Message pops up only at time of installation not on un-installation