# How can I print logs session with WIX toolset?

Tags: session, logging, wix

I'm still newbie and still learning how to do a good installer, but I have some questions again : **How can I print logs session?**

I have for example :

```
 [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CheckDatabaseExist(Session session)
    {

        try
        {

            session.Log("CheckDatabaseExist: Begin");

            var builder = getSqlConnectionsStringBuilder(session);
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {

                SqlCommand someCommand = new SqlCommand();
                someCommand.Connection = connection;
                someCommand.Parameters.Add("@databaseName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = session.CustomActionData["DATABASE_NAME"];

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT db_id('@databaseName')") ,connection))
                {

                      session.Log("command is: " + command);
                      if (command.ExecuteScalar() != DBNull.Value)
                      {
                          session["DATABASE_EXISTED"] = "1"; // existed
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          session["DATABASE_EXISTED"] = string.Empty; // did not exist
                      }

                }
            }

            session.Log("CheckDatabaseExist: End");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("CheckDatabaseExist: exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }


        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

I want to have all my log in a file?

I tried this command line :

```
msiexec /i DatabaseScriptsInstall.msi /L*V log.txt
```

But I do not have the session log...

Any idea?? It will be very helpful for me, I didn't find answer yet.

Thanks

Comment: Does the log say you are running the custom action in it? It should say something like `MSI (c) (50:3C) [10:59:23:794]: Doing action: <action name>` and if it doesnt run it you would see `MSI (c) (50:E8) [10:59:41:953]: Skipping action: <action name> (condition is false)`

Comment: Hi @BrianSutherland, Yes I have : `MSI (s) (C4:2C) [09:08:06:760]: Doing action: CheckDatabaseExist
Action 09:08:06: CheckDatabaseExist. 
Action start 09:08:06: CheckDatabaseExist.` and I can see my properties changing... but not the log :(

Comment: It looks fine so I don't see why there would be no logs. very odd. That's how I would log something just session.Log("string"); Not sure why the logs aren't appearing for you =[

Comment: oh bad news for me ! I suppose,  I've something different on my environment....  Did you build you MSI with a special behavior? I'm so hopeless

Comment: How are you running the custom action? According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494101/wix-c-sharp-custom-action-logging-not-working) you can't use logging from a control event (click a button and do a custom action based off the click).

Comment: Okay !! I read this article, but I didn't understand as well. So, it's a workarround (a bad one)? Thanks a lot!!! I used the control event to publish it!  I'll try to set my log in properties or can I use something else instead of the control event??